# NameError: free variable 'd' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to know if code is possible :

```
chs = ch.split(' ')
d = { mot:ch.count(mot) for mot in chs if (mot not in d)}
```

These instructions aim to create a dictionary, based on my knowledge in other programming languages, I understand that count would be done every time a loop is iterated, so what I'm trying to do is to optimise and not do the count if the word is already counted.

Now the problem is that i get this error

```
NameError: free variable 'd' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

which I totally understand, the variable `d` is not set yet.

So, what I'm looking for is to know if there is some temporary variable that has the values before enclosure.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do here but in `(mot not in d)` the `d` here is used before assignment.

Comment: @Anas: No, there isn't. You have to find another solution. What about using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: yes, the output is correct, but in case there is a word that is repeated 1000 times, the count will be done 1000 time, {'word':1000}
isnt there any way to verify if the word exists before the result is assigned ?

Comment: Create a set to loop over: `d = { mot:chs.count(mot) for mot in set(chs)`. But I still recommend the usage of `Counter`.

Comment: the counter is correct
let's say that 'a' exists 1000 times 
`for c in ch:
    ch.count(c)`
I would like to check before counting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be after this:

```
ch = 'a a b c d'
words = set(ch.split(' '))

d = { mot:ch.count(mot) for mot in words}
print(d)
```

Create a `set` of words. This way you only check unique words, once each.

Comment: the result is indeed a set, but I would like to verify if a word is already counted

Comment: What do you mean? Yes `words` is a `set`, but `d` remains a `dict`.

Comment: @Anas a word won't have been counted already, as `words` is a set, so there are no duplicates

Comment: so `dict` and `set` are two different things ? I see, I'll try it

Comment: I was thinking about a temporary variable that i can use to test on, but this works too.
thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if `mot` exists in `d` at all.

```
ch = 'a a b c d'
chs = ch.split(' ')
d = { mot:ch.count(mot) for mot in chs }
```

So now `d = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}`.

Comment: Now you don't need to initialise `d` at all.

Comment: I have already done that, now what I'm looking for is how not to count 'a' twice, if 'a' is present 1000 times, it will be counted 1000 times on each loop

Comment: what do you mean? can you show me what you want `d` to look like?

Comment: @Ollie - The output is correct, but the op is trying to reduce the calls to `count` where they aren't needed

Comment: looks like @quamrana has done this in their answer :)

Comment: `d` is correct, but one key is counted many time, how to verify if the key is counted before counting again